# How to calculate the solar irradiance (flux) on Mars. But,measurments are made at Earth orbit or at 1 AU

Tags: mars, solar-wind, maven

There are many satellites measuring the solar flux in EUV and X-ray at 1 AU (Ex: SDO, SOHO, etc).
In the case of Mars: MAVEN looking sun in a small band of EUV and X-ray at Mars. Is there any approach, that I can use measurement at 1AU (Because they have a wideband of observations) and extrapolate to Mars and beyond?.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

For spacecraft/astrodynamics modeling, the acceleration due to the solar radiation pressure is specified in units of the solar flux: Watt per square meter as measured at 1 AU. As derived in the [MathSpec of Nyx](https://nyxspace.com/MathSpec/models/srp/), to calculate the solar flux at any other point, simply divide the solar flux at 1 AU (which was about 1367 some years ago) by the norm squared of the vector from Mars (in your case) to the sun.

Comment: The page (link) is not opening!!.

Comment: @Martian that's odd, it works for me...